# Do you still use Visual Transform to keep an object (which has fallen) in its final place?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, collision

If I have 2 cloth items which fall onto multiple surfaces set to collide, how can I keep them in the final 'resting' position? Visual Transform does not work for me. Is there a new or different way to do this?

thanks

Comment: You do not use visual transform for cloth modifiers.  Visual transform writes the transform of the object.  Cloth physics is a *deformation* rather than a transformation: it has no effect on the object's location, rotation, or scale.  You can write that deformation into the mesh by applying modifiers, possibly as shapekeys.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll give it a try.